# Is there a way to pass data along with redirect after form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating a form to query some internal sources for some of our employees. The data received is coming back as JSON. But basically the flow is this:
HTML Form > to PHP > redirect data to HTML results page to be formatted nicely.

If there is a simpler way I am open for suggestions but I'm trying to pass the JSON that PHP script returns to the results page to be formatted nicely.

I tried using the example from w3schools but it's not working.

This is all on an internal Linux Web Server.

test.html

```
...

<form action="../dir/dir/xxx.php" method="GET"> 
 IOC/Indicator:<input type="text" name="ioc">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>

...
```

---

xxx.php

```
...

$result = print_r((curl_exec($ch)));
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);

header( 'Location: ../../dir/results.html' );

...
```

---

results.html

```
...
<p id="results"></p>
<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = myObj;
        } 
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../dir/dir/xxx.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>
...
```

End results should be on the lines of:
user submits IOC,
IOC gets ran through the PHP script,
user gets redirected to the results page where data from PHP script would be displayed

Comment: I'm not sure what you think [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) does in `$result = print_r((curl_exec($ch)));` but I doubt you need it.

Comment: The only reason to send the form data to .php is if you need some server-side processing done with the data (which often is the case). Redirecting from .php back to another HTML page to show the data is perfectly fine. But, stay as far away from W3 Schools as possible. It's well-known to have incorrect, outdated or missing information. Instead, learn from the [Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn)

Comment: in xxx.php, can you just output results instead of redirecting?

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("GET", "../dir/dir/xxx.php", true);` isn't going to be much good because a) ajax can't respond to redirects, but b) that's a good thing else the page would redirect to itself and c) you've already requested the results, they don't need to be requested again. Better idea: xxx.php just includes the formatting code and directly returns the formatted HTML. Or, you change xxx.php to return the data directly (without redirect), and instead test.html just sends the user to results.html where an ajax call runs and gets the data from xxx.php. But that falls down once you need params etc

Comment: You seem to have tied yourself in knots a bit here. Give it a re-think.

Comment: Maybe cut out the middle man and just make an Ajax request to xxx.php from the original Html form. Get xxx.php to just return the JSON without a redirect. Then when you get the result, use some JS to format the results and display it there and then. Not sure you need a separate results page really. That's the nice thing about Ajax, it can reduce all the jumping around between pages.

Comment: @Script47 when i left out 'print_r' i swear i didnt return it correctly but i will try that again.

Comment: @ADyson if taking your approach and just request the data from xxx.php with the user input, how would I keep the user from being automatically redirected to xxx.php when they click submit?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio was trying to keep the users away from xxx.php as much as possible really but I may do this as a last resort

Comment: You should redirect to another PHP script rather than an HTML page. Then you can either set session variables that the script displays, or add parameters to the URL in the redirect.

Comment: @SudoRm-F "how would I keep the user from being automatically redirected to xxx.php when they click submit?" ...your event handler (whether it handles the click on the submit button, or the "submit" event of the form itself) would need to `return false;` at the end to prevent the normal postback behaviour (btw this is something you can already easily [google yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+stop+form+submit&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=ajax+stop+form+submit&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.4234j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)